# How to find the xpath of a web element already located by selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

I used an xpath search by text to find an element I wanted to locate.

```
location = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(f"//*[text()='{i[0]} \u00a0']")
```

But now I also need the xpath of that element to find other things associated with it. Please help I haven't found anything to help at all. Only other thing I could think of is using bs4 to loop through all the elements on the page and find it but that seems like a very slow option to me.

Comment: location.find_element_by_xpath() to go inside an element.